# Bootstrap form always showing horizontal scroll

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, scroll, size

I'm designing a system which uses all bootstrap controls. on every page, an horizontal scroll is displayed. however there seems to be no control that is causing this. I give you the example of one of my pages. I think I have something wrong in the head, but I can not find it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?error_reporting(0);?>
<? include_once "include/checkSession.inc"; ?>
<? include_once "include/conexion.inc"; ?>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">
    <title>Clínica 25 de Mayo</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/bootstrap_flatly.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="include/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="include/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="include/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="bienvenido.php?login=<?=$textLogin;?>">Clínica 25 de Mayo</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="bienvenido.php?login=<?=$textLogin;?>">Inicio</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Mis Turnos <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="reservarTurno.php?login=<?=$textLogin;?>">Reservar Turno</a></li>
            <li><a href="listadoTurnosReservados.php?login=<?=$textLogin;?>">Ver Turnos Reservados</a></li>
            <li><a href="listadoTurnosReservadosEliminar.php?login=<?=$textLogin;?>">Anular Turno</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Mi Cuenta<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="pacientesBuscar.php?login=<?=$textLogin;?>">Ingreso de mis Datos y/o de Otra persona.</a></li>
            <li><a href="datosPersonales.php?login=<?=$textLogin;?>">Datos Propios</a></li>
            <li><a href="contrasenia.php?login=<?=$textLogin;?>">Cambiar Contraseña</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>   
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="logout.php?login=<?=$textLogin;?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Cerrar Sesión</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

    <form class="form-horizontal" name="formPwd" method="post" action="contraseniaGuardar.php">

    <h4 class="text-center text-primary">Complete el formulario para cambiar la contraseña de acceso al sistema del Usuario<br><b><?=$_SESSION["nombreUsr"]; ?>&nbsp;<?=$_SESSION["apellidoUsr"]; ?></b></h4>

    <input type="hidden" name="login" value="<?=$textLogin;?>">


    <h2 class="text-center text-primary">Ingrese su nueva contraseña</h2>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Contraseña anterior:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
               <input class="form-control" type="password" name="textAnterior" size="35" maxlength="50">
        </div>
     </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Nueva contraseña:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
               <input class="form-control" type="password" name="textNueva" size="35" maxlength="50">
        </div>
     </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Confirme la contraseña:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
               <input class="form-control" type="password" name="textConfirma" size="35" maxlength="50">
        </div>
     </div>




    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
            <input type="button" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" onClick="javascript:modificar();">
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
            <input type="button" value="Cancelar" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" onClick="javascript:cancelar();">
        </div>
    </div>  

    </form>
    </body>
```

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle about this error?

Comment: sorry, I could solve the problem.
the problem was the type of form. changed form-horizontal to form.

Comment: sorry, I could solve the problem.
the problem was the type of form. changed form-horizontal to form. that solved the problem. Thanks!